# How to calculate fair 3s1s basis levels

Tags: swaps, libor, ois

How would one calculate the fair level of 3s1s single currency basis swaps using simply the 1m & 3m libors and ois levels? (so you have fra-ois spread levels in both)

I understand that as the FRA-OIS basis widens, the fair level of 3s1s would increase, but unsure how that level is calculated?

So if one entered a 1y basis swap at Xbp over 1mth, how would the stub risk be hedged (in ois since libors are not tradeable) and how does that translate back to finding a fair 3s1s level?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3s 1s basis cannot be calculated in an arbitrage sense.  You can make some reasonable assumptions.  For example , if fra/iOS is tighter on s forward basis than spot, then 3s 1s is likely to have a similar term structure.  But flows in the market may move it away from intuitive levels.

Comment: thanks. if (theoretically) you had fra/ois markets for every 3m and 1m set, then the 3s1s could be implied by that?
ie if 1mth FRA-OIS is 15/14 and 3mth fra-ois is 30/29 for every day in this next year then the 1y 3s1s market implied is 16/14  (30-14) / (29-15)

Comment: yes that's true, with a minor quibble about daycount (30bp is quarterly, 14bp is monthly but it makes no difference at these rate levels)